django make migration command error for Table does not exist
We have the models.py file like this :
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True , blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20 , unique=True)


class Label(models.Model):
    COLORS = (
        ('blue' , 'blue'),
        ('red' , 'red'),
        ('light_green' , 'light_green'),
        ('black' , 'black'),
        ('white' , 'white'),
        ('orange' , 'orange'),
        ('purple' , 'purple'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30 , choices=COLORS)
    

class Skill_Name(models.Model):
    label = models.ForeignKey(Label , on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True , blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    have_different_cars = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Skill(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car , on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True , blank=True)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill_Name , on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True , blank=True)


class Provider(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name="user_provider")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill , blank=True)

And when we try to makemigration we get the error that :
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'arenadatabase.providers_skill_name' doesn't exist")
i think that order of migration is not right! So I deleted migration files to migrate the app again but It does not worked for me!
anybody can help me please?

There will not be a table with such name, considering the Models you provided. Since, as default ManyToManyField uses the name of the m2m field and the name of the table for the model that contains it. (Which would be arenadatabase.provider_skills). So, it seems that you've made modifications to your models without mentioning...in any case, it is not possible to access a table that does not exist.
